# Error with cabal update

Tags: haskell, cabal

On a fresh install install of Haskell-Platform (64 bit OSX version from http://www.haskell.org/platform/mac.html) I get the following error:

```
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
Warning: http error: Network.Browser.request: Error raised ErrorParse "Invalid
cabal: Char.intToDigit: not a digit -1
```

After issuing the command `cabal update`. No luck with any searches and I have no idea where this error is coming from.

Comment: What's the output of `cabal --version`?

Comment: cabal-install version 1.16.0.2
    using version 1.16.0 of the Cabal library

Comment: Have you tried verbose mode yet? `cabal update --verbose=3`.  You might consider post the output to a gist if it is useful output.

Comment: It isn't particularly helpful, but here it is: https://gist.github.com/dansheffler/47ea9c951a49e55e398a#file-gistfile1-txt

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The only workaround I could find was to switch from hackage to [stackage](http://new-www.haskell.org/downloads).

In your `.cabal/config.cabal/config` file, you specify something like the following:

`-- remote-repo: hackage.haskell.org:http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive
remote-repo: stackage:http://www.stackage.org/stackage/24e4d1b3bb101a80d3be1b146771c13df0827a82`

Notice that hackage.haskell.org has to be commented out.

After that `cabal update` just worked.

I would be interested to here about other solutions though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the relevant bug ticket on the HTTP tracker: https://github.com/haskell/HTTP/issues/98

It seems to be a (rare) issue with certain network configurations that result in (slightly) invalid results being returned and the HTTP library being overly strict.

Installing a recent version of the `cabal` executable (a binary is available for download from the cabal website) will provide a workaround, in that the default transport (and it is configurable) is https, not http, and that transport will call out to `curl` or `wget`, which are more lax in how they handle parsing http responses.