# Haskell cabal update error Network.Browser.request

Tags: haskell, warnings, cabal, doctest

I have just installed haskell and I am trying to get a few more packages, such as doctest. When I run "cabal update", I get :

> Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
>
> Warning: http error: Network.Browser.request: Error raised ErrorParse "InvalidChar.intToDigit: not a digit -1

Do you have any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: what does your .cabal file look like?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24435856/error-with-cabal-update. Take a look at the answers to that question and see if they resolve your problem!

Comment: @jkeuhlen The .cabal is unmodified from a fresh install of haskell. I have tried the things on the possible duplicate. This does not seem to solve the problem.

Comment: Did you check your cabal version? The other SO question mentioned there is a bug for this in one version. Possibly try to get a more updated version of cabal?

Comment: cabal --version gives me "cabal-install version 1.24.0.0
compiled using version 1.24.0.0 of the Cabal library". The one from the other thread is 1.16

Comment: I tried using different versions of haskell and cabal today. I tried 4 different versions of each, and I got the same error on all of them.